# proper way of using variables in html tags

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am always confused when it comes to use variables (php or js) in html tags. Most of my time is wasted on it while coding. Searched on the internet but it is covered nowhere in every aspect.

```
var variableToUse;

elem.append('<input type="text" value="variableToUse">');
elem.append('<div class="variableToUse" style="background-color: variableToUse">variableToUse</div>');
```

and in case of php

```
$variableToUse;

$query = "SELECT $variableToUse, $variableToUse, $variableToUse FROM table WHERE name=$variableToUse and email=$variableToUse";
elem.append('<input type="text" value="$variableToUse">');
elem.append('<div class="$variableToUse" style="background-color: $variableToUse">$variableToUse</div>');
```

These are some scenarios where I am always confused, if you can explain that would be really helpful. Or if you can give more examples or possible scenario.

Comment: In _JavaScript_, say you have `var foo = 'fizz', bar = 'buzz';` then `foo + bar; // gives "fizzbuzz"`

Comment: "string interpolation" is a term you should search. FYI, ECMAScript 6 offers new string template syntax `\`<input type="text" value="${variableToUse}">\`` Notice the backticks are used to create the string instead of quotes.

Comment: @squint thank you for mentioning the term. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP, you use a `.` between variables and strings; the strings are embedded in quotation marks:

```
<?php 
$variable = "Morning";
echo "Good ".$variable; ?>
?>
```

...will result in "Good Morning"

In JS, the variables are NOT in quotation marks and instead of `.`you use `+`to connect variables and strings

```
<script>
var variable = "Morning";
var complete_name = "Good" + variable;
</script>
```

However, in JS there is no "echo" functionality.

---

ADDITIONAL STUFF (EDITED): As @Chris O'Kelly wrote, just treat HTML links in JS like regular strings:

PHP:

```
<?php echo '<input type="text" value='.$yourvariable.'">'; ?>
```

JS:

```
<script>elem.append('<input type="text" value="' + yourvariable + '">');</script>
```

(spaces around `+` can also be omitted)

Comment: i know these basics, I am asking about usage in html tags as I gave examples, if you can explain those :)

Comment: Your HTML Tags are really just strings, so `var className = 'foo'; elem.append('<div class="' + className + '"></div>')`

Comment: @ChrisO'Kelly please explain my examples